# What is this weird thing that border="50%" does?

Tags: html, css

Below is a table.

```html
<table border="50%">
        <tr>
            <th>Hello</th>
            <th>World!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

How can border be given just 50% and nothing else as a value? What is the black area surrounding the table? Why is one side of the black area darker than the other?

Comment: The `border` attribute (not to be confused with the `border` CSS style) can only be set in pixels and doesn't use a unit specifier. The `%` is ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [w3](https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-border-attribute.php), the border attribute is available for tables. It accepts a value in `px` units. It can be used to set border to a table. The greater the value, the thicker the border. If we set the value of this attribute to 0, then the table will have no border. There is no default value for this attribute.

It can accept any value, not just 50. When you used `50%` as the value, it ignored the % and set a border of 50px to the table.

However, we don't have any control over the style of the border created using `border` attribute. This is why we should use the css `border` property to set borders because we can customize the appearance of the border.

Here is a snippet for your reference -

```html
<!--No unit, just the value-->

<table border="50">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
</table>

<!--Same here. It ignores % and sets a border of 50px-->

<table border="50%">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
</table>

<!--It can have any value-->

<table border="15">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
</table>

<!--If its value is set to 0, then table will not have any border-->

<table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you specify the border in `%` it will ignore the `%` and consider it to be in px, which is the reason why border looks so bold!!!
Either you could specify border in px like:

```
<table border="2px">
```

or you could use inline css or any css as per your convenience:

```
<table style="border:2px solid black">
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML does not support values in `px`, `%`, or any other units in the `border` attribute of tables. But, if you put values in `px` or `%`, HTML will still render the border.

This is the format for applying a table border:
`<table border="n|0">...</table>`
where `n` is any integer after **1** (only **positive** values). If you give a value of `0`, it will produce a borderless table.

The black area is produced just because of a large value of `50` (percentage will be neglected by the browser).

Answer (score -2):

The HTML  border Attribute is used to specify the border of a table. It sets the border around the table cells.

```
<table border="1">
```

or

```
<table border="0">
```

1: It sets the border around the table cells.
0: It removes (not set) the border around the table cells.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table